# How to access my SD card of Moto G 2nd from Win7

Tags: sd-card, motorola-droid

All, I am in trouble with accessing the files , photos etc in my SD card of Moto G 2nd. Is there any way to make it ? Thanks.

**Updated**

It is my mistake, I am sorry that I didn't put it clear. Please forgive me . 
I mean I was trying access it from computer desktop. But so far didn't get it work around. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have an SD card.
Nor does it have a file explorer.

Download and install ES file manager from the play store to fix.

Comment: Excuse me, Did I mistake something?

Answer (score 1):

Well, inorder to access the SD card content over the device you are going to need a file manager app to do that, if you head over to the Google PlayStore then you can find a number of file explorer available that you can use. Just in case if you want you can try installing [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en) over your device. Once done open the ES File Explorer to look out for the files and folder over your SD card.